# Multiple dex file

Tags: dex

I imported one project into my eclipse ADT and on running it, I got below mentioned problem.

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same problem recently from adding a .jar library to my project. I got the following error...

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/act/LC/R$array;

The jar file contains the resources classes, however Eclipse is going to build these resources  when it compiles the project. It is for this reason why we have to delete the resource files from the jar file so that the project compiles.

Open the jar file with WinRar in your project folder and remove the R$ classes as well as the R.class file. Now run the project in Eclipse.

Obviously there is more than one solution to this problem but this one happened to work for me.